# How to make a tooltip for incoming list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a tooltip with JQuery for incoming list items. People will enter some text in a textfield, hit enter and those values will be added to a visible list on the site. I want to make a tooltip for every list item that will be added to the list. I want the text that people fill in in the textfield to be added in the tooltip, is this possible? And how can I do this? Thanks! This is what I have so far..

```
<div id="tooltip"></div>

<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Voer item in" /> <button id="button">Toevoegen</button>

<ul id="boodschappenlijst">


  </ul>

        ----------------------------------------------------------------------------




 $(document).ready(function(e) {

      $('#button').on('click', function (){

      var toevoegen = $('#input').val();
      var verwijderen = '<a href = "#" class = "verwijderen">Verwijderen</a>'


      <!--add list item-->

      $('#boodschappenlijst').prepend('<li>' + toevoegen + '' + '\t' + verwijderen + '</li>');

    });


    <!--remove list item-->


    $('#boodschappenlijst').on('click', '.verwijderen', function(){

      $(this).parent('li').remove();

    });

    <!-textfield empty-->


    $('#input').on('click', function (){

      $(this).val('')

    });


    $('#boodschappenlijst').hover(

    function (){

      $('#tooltip').css('display', 'block')
    },

    function (){

      $('#tooltip').css('display', 'none')
    };

    );


    }) ;

    ----------------------------------------------------------------

    #tooltip {

      position: absolute;
      top: 100px;
      right: 300px;
      border: 1px solid #000000;
      border-radius: 5px;
      color: black;
      width: 100px;
      display: none;

    }
```

---

The tooltip appears, but I want the text that people fill in in the textfield to be added in the tooltip. If you need some more information just ask. Thanks in advance (verwijderen = remove, toevoegen = add)

Comment: could you post your html structure?

Comment: it's added at the top screen now

Answer (score 2):

There are two  main changes you need to make:

1. You need to store `toevoegen` with the `li` in a structured way.
2. You need to attach the hover event to the `li`, not the `ul` - or more specifically any `li`s which are added to the `ul` in future.

For 1. you can use the jquery [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store the tooltip value:

```
var li = $('<li>' + toevoegen + '' + '\t' + verwijderen + '</li>');
li.data('tooltip', toevoegen);
$('#boodschappenlijst').prepend(li);
```

For 2. you will need to use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `hover()` to ensure that new `li`s get the event attached:

```
$('#boodschappenlijst').on('mouseenter', 'li', function () {
    var toevoegen = $(this).data('tooltip');
    $('#tooltip').css('display', 'block').html(toevoegen);
}).on('mouseleave', 'li', function () {
    $('#tooltip').css('display', 'none').html('');
});
```

Here is the full thing, tidied up:

```js
$(document).ready(function (e) {

    $('#button').on('click', function () {
        var toevoegen = $('#input').val();
        var verwijderen = '<a href="#" class="verwijderen">Verwijderen</a>'
        //add list item
        var li = $('<li>' + toevoegen + '' + '\t' + verwijderen + '</li>');
        li.data('tooltip', toevoegen);
        $('#boodschappenlijst').prepend(li);
    });

    // remove list item
    $('#boodschappenlijst').on('click', '.verwijderen', function () {
        $(this).parent('li').remove();
    });

    // textfield empty
    $('#input').on('click', function () {
        $(this).val('');
    });

    $('#boodschappenlijst').on('mouseenter', 'li', function () {
        var toevoegen = $(this).data('tooltip');
        $('#tooltip').css('display', 'block').html(toevoegen);
    }).on('mouseleave', 'li', function () {
        $('#tooltip').css('display', 'none').html('');
    });
});
```

```css
 #tooltip {
     position: absolute;
     top: 100px;
     right: 300px;
     border: 1px solid #000000;
     border-radius: 5px;
     color: black;
     width: 100px;
     display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tooltip"></div>

<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Voer item in" /> <button id="button">Toevoegen</button>

<ul id="boodschappenlijst"></ul>
```

Comment: I am upvoting this answer because I actually learned something from it. Nice of use of on mouseenter li ...... my code destroys and recreates hover handler for each new item...which is not the most efficient way. But I am leaving mine up for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATED ANSWER.

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/60rnneo0/23/)

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

var myToolTip = $('#tooltip');

  $('#button').on('click', function (){

  var toevoegen = $('#input').val();
  var verwijderen = '<a href = "#" class = "verwijderen">Verwijderen</a>'




  $('#boodschappenlijst').prepend('<li class=\'hoverTarget\' title=\''+toevoegen+' \'>' + toevoegen + '' + '\t' + verwijderen + '</li>');



      $('.hoverTarget').hover(

          function (_evt){

          console.log("e",_evt);

          console.log("e",_evt.currentTarget.attributes['title']);


           myToolTip.html(_evt.currentTarget.attributes['title'].value);      

           myToolTip.css('display', 'block')
},

function (){

  myToolTip.css('display', 'none')
}

);

});





$('#boodschappenlijst').on('click', '.verwijderen', function(){

  $(this).parent('li').remove();

});


$('#input').on('click', function (){

  $(this).val('')

});





}) ;
```

Add title attribute to your line item

```
 $('#boodschappenlijst').prepend('<li title=\''+toevoegen+'\'>' + toevoegen + '' + '\t' + verwijderen + '</li>');
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, this could be a idea also. Tried it but now the title is showing in the standard windows tooltip. But I would like the title to be shown in the <div id = "tooltip">

Comment: As shown, there is more than one way to skin a cat.

Both answers are valid.  :)

Comment: You should accept his answer so he gets the points.....but you could also upvote mine. ;-)

Comment: If I could I gave you both ++rep pal, but I saw I did not have enough rep. to do that :( (I'm not very often on this site)